# Remove Curl and libcurl or Update it to latest version (>=8.0) in Docker in Nginx base image

Tags: linux, bash, docker, nginx, curl

I have a base image called `docker-base` which has a Dockerfile as shown below:

```
FROM nginx:latest

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /var/www/app

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Install app dependencies
COPY app-nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

COPY motd /etc/motd

RUN chmod 0644 /etc/motd; echo '[ ! -z "$TERM" -a -r /etc/motd ] && cat /etc/motd' >> /etc/bash.bashrc

COPY usersessiontimout.sh /etc/profile.d/usersessiontimout.sh

RUN chmod +x /etc/profile.d/usersessiontimout.sh

EXPOSE 8000
```

It uses the latest node version and the image is built using debain bookworm as shown below when I run the container from the image

```
root@e4f1d0771272:/var/www/app# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

But it shows version of curl and libcurl as below

```
docker exec e4f1d0771272 dpkg -l | grep curl
ii  curl                      7.88.1-10+deb12u4              arm64        command line tool for transferring data with URL syntax
ii  libcurl4:arm64            7.88.1-10+deb12u4              arm64        easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL flavour)
```

I tried updating it to version (>=8.0), but as per the [official document](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=curl) the latest curl version in debian packages which nginx uses is 7.88.1.

I tried removing the curl and libcurl from the base image by adding the followuing in the above Dockerfile.

```
RUN apt-get remove -y --auto-remove curl libcurl
```

But when I built my dependent image using the base and ran the container it keeps restarting.
My dependent image Dockerfile as below:

```
# Stage 1: Build stage
FROM node:12.3.1-alpine AS build

# Use different mirrors
RUN sed -i -e 's/dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/mirrors.aliyun.com/g' /etc/apk/repositories

# Install necessary packages using the 'apk' package manager
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache wget build-base openssl-dev

# Set the source folder
ARG SOURCE_FOLDER="./"
ARG BUILD_VERSION
ARG NPM_TOKEN

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /var/www/app

# Bundle app source
COPY ${SOURCE_FOLDER} .

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache bash git openssh && \
    npm config set unsafe-perm true && \
    echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN" > .npmrc && \
    npm i -g @myorg/lsc && \
    npm i --quiet --cache=./npm-cache

# Build the application
RUN NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 lsc build site --output-hashing all --buildVersion=$BUILD_VERSION && \
    rm -f .npmrc

# Stage 2: Final stage
FROM myorg/docker-base

# Copy only the necessary artifacts from the build stage
COPY --from=build /var/www/app/dist/ngx-rsc-app /var/www/app


# Install necessary packages using 'apt-get' package manager
RUN apt-get update 


# Switch back to app directory
WORKDIR /var/www/app
```

This is the error from the container logs of the dependendent image that was built

```
root@ip:~# docker logs -f 77666b51984a
exec /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
exec /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
exec /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
exec /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
```

Any idea why its throwing this error and possible resolution? Also, is there a better way to remove the the existing curl and libcurl and also keep the container healthy? Or update it to a version >=8.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked was using nginx based on alpine image, which doesn't have curl and libcurl packages installed. I retained the nginx configurations from `myorg/docker-base`. Here is the complete solution:

**Dockerfile of my docker-base image**

```
FROM nginx:latest

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /var/www/app

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Install app dependencies
COPY app-nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

COPY motd /etc/motd

RUN chmod 0644 /etc/motd; echo '[ ! -z "$TERM" -a -r /etc/motd ] && cat /etc/motd' >> /etc/bash.bashrc

COPY usersessiontimout.sh /etc/profile.d/usersessiontimout.sh

RUN chmod +x /etc/profile.d/usersessiontimout.sh

EXPOSE 8000
```

**Dockerfile of my dependent image**

```
# Stage 1: Build stage
FROM node:12.3.1-alpine AS build

# Use different mirrors
RUN sed -i -e 's/dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/mirrors.aliyun.com/g' /etc/apk/repositories

# Install necessary packages using the 'apk' package manager
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache wget build-base openssl-dev

# Set the source folder
ARG SOURCE_FOLDER="./"
ARG BUILD_VERSION
ARG NPM_TOKEN

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /var/www/app

# Bundle app source
COPY ${SOURCE_FOLDER} .

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache bash git openssh && \
    npm config set unsafe-perm true && \
    echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN" > .npmrc && \
    npm i -g @myorg/lsc && \
    npm i --quiet --cache=./npm-cache

# Build the application
RUN NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 lsc build site --output-hashing all --buildVersion=$BUILD_VERSION && \
    rm -f .npmrc

# Stage 2: Nginx configuration stage
FROM myorg/docker-base:latest AS nginx-conf

# Stage 3: Final nginx image
FROM nginx:stable-alpine-slim

# Copy the build output and nginx configuration
COPY --from=build /var/www/app/dist/ngx-rsc-app /var/www/app
COPY --from=nginx-conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/app-nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

# Set ownership and permissions for NGINX directories, files and create the Nginx process ID file
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/app /var/cache/nginx /var/log/nginx /etc/nginx \
    && touch /var/run/nginx.pid \
    && chown nginx:nginx /var/run/nginx.pid \
    && rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Install net-tools to provide network diagnostic tools
RUN apk add --no-cache net-tools

# Set the Nginx user
USER 101

# Run Nginx with the command "nginx -g daemon off;"
CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

The container logs of the dependent image that was built, doesn't show any curl or libcurl anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Errm... Shouldn't you have either a docker `ENTRYPOINT` or docker `CMD` instruction somewhere in your docker file? How did it decide /docker-entrypoint.sh was your entrypoint, and where do you copy that file into the container?

In any case, for the exec() system call to be able to execute a shell script it needs (a) to have the x bit set. i.e. `chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh`. (b) it needs to have `#!/bin/bash` (or whatever shell) at the beginning. That error would indicate that it probably doesn't.

Comment: That’s what it’s said when I asked ChatGPT as well. But there is no docker-entrypoint.sh file, not sure why is it showing that error, when there is no such file

Comment: @merilstack Maybe it's the default or something. In any case, where do YOU think your entry point is? You haven't set one up as far as I can see. And knowing where it is and what it does is the most important part of setting up your container.

Comment: The base image at the top of the question is built `FROM nginx`, which includes both an `ENTRYPOINT` wrapper and a default `CMD`.

Comment: @DavidMaze I did add `ENTRYPOINT` wrapper and a default `CMD` in the last 2 lines of my Dockerfile
`ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
CMD ["nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]`
But still my container, build with this as base image errors out
`exec /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error`